# How to translate "embed" in German?

Tags: meaning, translation

I'm a native German speaker, but I don't find the correct translation for the word "embed".

The word embed is used in sentences like:

> You could also link to a website to embed session content.
>
> Embed a link.

What is the correct translation of it?

Comment: Tell us why you're not satisfied with the translations "einbetten" and "einschließen". This could help finding another or better word

Comment: Because I don't think that this matches to something technical on a computer. Or what does Einbetten actually mean. Einschliessen is something else its like you close yourself or something like.

Comment: Wenn du deutsch sprichst und deutsch bist, wie du behauptest, warum frägst du dann nicht auf Deutsch?

Comment: Your example sentence makes nearly no sense, probably this is why you don't understand, are you sure you did cite correct?

Comment: @Jan: Ich kann verstehen, daß man geneigt ist, in Englisch zu fragen, die Seite heißt nun mal German Language, vlt. ein Grundsatzproblem?!

Comment: @Thomas wahrscheinlich nicht ganz falsch. Andererseits heißt es am Anfang der [Tour] (und wahrscheinlich anderswo) auch *bilingual question and answer site.* Vielleicht sollte man in die Tour noch explizit reinschreiben, dass man auch auf Deutsch fragen kann …? Eine Diskussion für [Meta]! http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1221

Comment: Thomas is right: you do not embed a link, you do only embed content. When you look [here](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/HTML/Multimedia_und_Grafiken/Aktive_Inhalte_einbinden), you can see, that "einbinden" is another possible translation. But you find a lot of sites, where you do "Inhalt einbetten", e. g. "Videos einbetten" and so on.

Comment: Zu wenig Kontext; wenn damit gemeint ist, dass man Inhalte entweder in die Seite hineinkopiert (Achtung, Urheberrecht), oder nur ein(en) Link auf eine Seite setzt, die das Gewünschte enthält, könnte *verlinken* (ergänze: des gewünschten Inhalts) das passende Wort sein. Ich bin zwar kein Freund deutscher Vorsilben für englische Wortstämme, aber das wird häufig so verwendet.

Answer (score 5):

There are two possible translations of "embed": *einbetten* or *einbinden*

*[Einbetten](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/einbetten)* means *etwas in etwas Größeres einfügen*. *[Einbinden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einbinden)* means *durch feste [Ver]bindung einbeziehen, einfügen*.

For me, *einbetten* is more visual and about the presentation of the small thing within the big thing, whereas *einbinden* emphasizes the connection of the both things.

Thus, I would translate

> You could also link to a website to embed session content.

as `Du könntest also auch zu einer Webseite verlinken um Inhalte der Session einzubinden` because the purpose of the link is to include session content to the website.

and

> Embed a link.

as `Einen Link (in einer Webseite) einbetten` if I want to emphasize the way the link is presented in the website. E.g., I think my links to Duden and Wiktionary are *eingebettet*, because the content is already in my answer and the link is just the reference

or as `Einen Link (in einer Webseite) einbinden` if I want to emphasize the connection of the content of the link to the website.

Answer (score 2):

[OLE Object Linking and Embedding - German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding)

OLE has been introduced by Microsoft in the 1990s. And in this case "Einbettung" is used. If you just want to add a link you can also use Einfügen. Similarly to embedding a crystal or a diamond into a ring or brooch.

> Object Linking and Embedding (OLE, engl. Objekt-Verknüpfung und -Einbettung) ist ein von Microsoft entwickeltes Objektsystem und Protokoll, das die Zusammenarbeit unterschiedlicher (OLE-fähiger) Applikationen und damit die Erstellung heterogener Verbunddokumente ermöglichen soll.

Answer (score 1):

"Einbetten" is 100% the right translation.

Comment: Giving an example - in this case a translation of one entire sentence - increases the value of an answer.

Comment: Could you please motivate your statement?